# Error message: ! Missing } inserted. <inserted text> } l.116 \end{thebibliography}

Tags: bibtex, errors

I am getting the following error message when I run my code:

> ! Missing } inserted.  }
>   l.116 \end{thebibliography}

I have read previous questions like this on here which say the error is in my bibliography and not main code but I cannot find a missing bracket in my bibliography or anything else which could be causing the issue before line 116.

Here is my bibliography; (I  have put < line 116> to show you where this is, please note this is not apart of my actual code)

```
@ARTICLE{FossKorshunovZachary2013,
  AUTHOR    = {S. Foss and D. Korshunov and S. Zachary},
  TITLE     = {Heavy-tailed and long-tailed distributions},
  BOOKTITLE = {An Introduction to Heavy-Tailed and Subexponential 
Distributions},
  PAGES     = {7--42},
  YEAR      = {2013},
  PUBLISHER = {Springer}}

@misc{ParetoDist2011,
  TITLE        = {The Pareto Distribution},
  YEAR         = {2011},
  HOWPUBLISHED = 
{url{https://statisticalmodeling.wordpress.com/2011/06/25/the-mean-excess-
loss-function}},
   LAST EDITED  = {23 June 2011}, 
  NOTE         = {"[Online; accessed 30 August 2017]"}}

@ARTICLE{Rojas-NandayapaXie2017,
  AUTHOR    = {L. Rojas-Nandayapa and W. Xie},
  TITLE     = {Asympotoic tail behavior of phase-type scale mixture 
 distributions},
  YEAR      = {2017},
  PAGES     = {1--6},
  JOURNAL   = {Annals of Actuarial Science},
  PUBLISHER = {Cambridge University Press}}

@BOOK{BuchholzKriegeFelko2014,
  AUTHOR    = {P. Buchholz, J. Kriege, I. Felko},
  TITLE     = {Phase-Type Distributions},
  PUBLISHER = {Springer},
  YEAR      = {2014},
  PAGES     = {5--10, 125--128}}

@ARTICLE{BladtNandayapapa2017,
  AUTHOR    = {M. Bladt and L. Nandayapapa},
  TITLE     = {Fitting Phase-type Mixtures to Heavy-tailed Data and 
Distriutions},
  YEAR      = {2017},
  JOURNAL   = {arXiv preprint arXiv:1705.04357},
  PAGES     = {1--11}}

@article{AhmSoohanKimJosephRamaswani2012,
  AUTHOR    = {Ahn, Soohan and H.T. Kim, Joseph and Ramaswami, V},
  TITLE     = {A New Class of Models for Heavy Tailed Distributions in 
Finance and Insurance Risk},
  YEAR      = {2012},
  MONTH     = {07},
  VOLUME    = {51},
  BOOKTITLE = {Insurance: Mathematics and Economics}}

@misc{wikipedia2017,
  AUTHOR       = {Wikipedia®},
  TITLE        = {Heavy-tailed distribution},
  HOWPUBLISHED = {url{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heavy-
tailed_distribution}},
 LAST EDITED  = {10 June 2017}, 
  NOTE         = {"[Online; accessed 10 June 2017]"}}

 @misc{Zheng,
  AURTHOR      = {S. Zheng},
  TITLE        = {Sufficient Statistics and Exponential Family Lecturer},
  YEAR         = {n.d},
  HOWPUBLISHED =
 {url{http://people.missouristate.edu/songfengzheng/Teaching/MTH541/Lecture\%20no
tes/Sufficient.pdf}},
  NOTE         = {"[Online; accessed 31 June 2017]"}}

@misc{Clapham2016,
  AURTHOR      = {M.E. Clapham},
  TITLE        = {Maximum likelihood estimation},
  YEAR         = {2016},
  HOWPUBLISHED = {url{https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2vh98ful3_M}},
  LAST EDITED  = {05 March 2016}, 
  NOTE         = {"[Online; accessed 01 August 2017]"}}

@misc{Andale2015,
  AURTHOR      = {Andale},
  TITLE        = {Pareto Distribution Definition},
  YEAR         = {2015},
  HOWPUBLISHED = {url{http://www.statisticshowto.com/pareto-distribution}},
  LAST EDITED  = {06 May 2015}, 
  NOTE         = {"[Online; accessed 22 July 2017]"}}

@phdthesis{Vatamidou2015,
  AUTHOR = {Vatamidou, Eleni},
  TITLE  = {Error analysis of structured Markov chains},
  YEAR   = {2015},
  SCHOOL = {Technische Universiteit Eindhoven}}  

@article{AsmussenNermanOlsson1996,
  AUTHOR    = {S. Asmussen and O. Nerman and M. Olsson}, 
  TITLE     = {Fitting Phase-Type Distributions via the EM Algorithm},
  YEAR      = {1996},
  ISSN      = {03036898, 14679469},
  URL       = {http://www.jstor.org/stable/4616418}, 
  JOURNAL   = {Scandinavian Journal of Statistics}, 
  NUMBER    = {4},
  PAGES     = {419--441},
  PUBLISHER = {Board of the Foundation of the Scandinavian Journal of 
  Statistics, Wiley},
  VOLUME    = {23}}

 @inproceedings{TaoRojasTaimre2016,
 AUTHOR       = {H. Yao and L. Rojas-Nandayapa, and T. Taimre},
 TITLE        = {Estimating tail probabilities of random sums of infinite 
mixtures of phase-type distributions},
 YEAR         = {2016},
 BOOKTITLE    = {Proceedings of the 2016 Winter Simulation Conference},
 PAGES       = {347--358},
 ORGANISATION = {IEEE Press}}

@article{AsmussenNermanOlsson1996,
  AUTHOR    = {Figueiredo, Mario AT}, 
  TITLE     = {Lecture Notes on the EM Algorithm},
  YEAR      = {2004},
  JOURNAL={URL{http://www.stat.duke.edu/courses/Spring06/sta376/Support/EM/EM.Mixtures.}},
    PUBLISHER = {Citeseer}}

 @article{Breuer2014,
  AUTHOR   = {Breuer, Lothar},
  TITLE    = {Introduction to stochastic processes},
  YEAR     = {2014},
  JOURNAL  = {Lecture Notes, Univ. Kent}}

@phdthesis{Esparza2010,
 <LINE 116>     AUTHOR   = {Esparza, Luz Judith R and Nielsen, Bo Friis and Bladt, 
Mogens},
  TITLE    = {Maximum likelihood estimation of phase-type distributions},
  YEAR     = {2010},
  SCHOOL   = {Technical University of DenmarkDanmarks Tekniske Universitet, 
Department of Applied                    Mathematics and Computer 
ScienceInstitut for Matematik og Computer Science}}

 @article{Brazauskas2016,
  AUTHOR    = {V. Brazauskas and A. Kleefeld},
  TITLE     = {Modeling severity and measuring tail risk of Norwegian fire 
 claims},
  YEAR      = {2016},
  JOURNAL   = {North American Actuarial Journal},
  VOLUME    = {20},
  NUMBER    = {1},
  PAGES     = {1--16},
  PUBLISHER = {Taylor \& Francis}}

@article{Dempster1977,
  AUTHOR    = {Dempster, Arthur P and Laird, Nan M and Rubin, Donald B},
  TITLE     = {Maximum likelihood from incomplete data via the EM 
algorithm},
  YEAR      = {1977},
  JOURNAL   = {Journal of the royal statistical society. Series B 
(methodological)},
  PAGES     = {1--38},
  PUBLISHER = {JSTOR}}

@article{Borman2004,
  AUTHOR    = {Borman, Sean},
  TITLE     = {The expectation maximization algorithm - a short tutorial},
  YEAR      = {2004},
  JOURNAL   = {Submitted for publication},
  PAGES     = {1--9}}


@misc{wikipediaPowerLaw2017,
  AUTHOR       = {Wikipedia®},
  TITLE        = {Power Law},
  HOWPUBLISHED = {url{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_law}},
  LAST EDITED  = {12 July 2017}, 
  NOTE         = {"[Online; accessed 12 July 2017]"}}

@book{Embrechts2013,
  AUTHOR    = {Embrechts, Paul and Kluppelberg, Claudia and Mikosch, 
Thomas},
  TITLE     = {Modelling extremal events: for insurance and finance},
  YEAR      = {2013},
  VOLUME    = {33},
  PUBLISHER = {Springer Science \& Business Media}}

@misc{Mean2011,
  TITLE        = {The mean excess loss function},
  YEAR         = {2011},
  HOWPUBLISHED = 
{url{https://statisticalmodeling.wordpress.com/2011/06/25/the-mean-excess-
loss-function/}},
  LAST EDITED  = {25 June 2011}, 
  NOTE         = {"[Online; accessed 30 August 2017]"}}

@article{Genccay2001,
  TITLE        = {EVIM: A software package for extreme value analysis in 
MATLAB},
  AUTHOR       = {Genccay, Ramazan and Selccuk, Faruk and Ulugulyagci, 
Abdurrahman},
  JOURNAL      = {Studies in Nonlinear Dynamics \& Econometrics},
  VOLUMN       = {5},
  NUMBER       = {3},
  YEAR         = {2001}}

@article{Mcneil1997,
       title={Estimating the tails of loss severity distributions using 
extreme 
   value theory},
       author={McNeil, Alexander J},
       journal={ASTIN Bulletin: The Journal of the IAA},
      volume={27},
      number={1},
      pages={117--137},
       year={1997},
       publisher={Cambridge University Press}}
```

Comment: the line number is the line in the generated bibliography (with `\end{thebibliography}` but the error is there at the end of the group as there is a mismatched `{` earlier.

Comment: Are you processing your BibTeX file using a UTF8 encoding? The entry `wikipedia2017` has that in it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have several mistakes in your given bib code.  Let us look to bib entry `ParetoDist2011`.  The corrected version is:

```
@misc{ParetoDist2011,
  TITLE        = {The Pareto Distribution},
  YEAR         = {2011},
  howpublished = {\url{https://statisticalmodeling.wordpress.com/2011/06/25/the-mean-excess-loss-function}},
  LAST_EDITED  = {23 June 2011}, 
  NOTE         = {"[Online; accessed 30 August 2017]"},
}
```

You missed an `\`before `url{`, the blank in `LAST EDITED` results in an error message (`missing =`).  In other entrys you masked in urls `%` with `\%`. After loading package `url` or `hyperref` that is not longer needed ...

The following MWE compiles without errors and only one warning (okay, commes from used package `filecontents` to keep bib file and TeX code together in one MWE):

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{Goossens,
  author    = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach, Frank and 
               Samarin, Alexander},
  title     = {The LaTeX Companion},
  edition   = {1},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  location  = {Reading, Mass.},
  year      = {1994},
}
@Book{adams,
  title     = {The Restaurant at the End of the Universe},
  author    = {Douglas Adams},
  series    = {The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy},
  publisher = {Pan Macmillan},
  year      = {1980},
}
@ARTICLE{FossKorshunovZachary2013,
  AUTHOR    = {S. Foss and D. Korshunov and S. Zachary},
  TITLE     = {Heavy-tailed and long-tailed distributions},
  BOOKTITLE = {An Introduction to Heavy-Tailed and Subexponential Distributions},
  journal   = {MISSING},
  PAGES     = {7--42},
  YEAR      = {2013},
  PUBLISHER = {Springer},
}
@misc{ParetoDist2011,
  TITLE        = {The Pareto Distribution},
  YEAR         = {2011},
  howpublished = {\url{https://statisticalmodeling.wordpress.com/2011/06/25/the-mean-excess-loss-function}},
  LAST_EDITED  = {23 June 2011}, 
  NOTE         = {"[Online; accessed 30 August 2017]"},
}
@ARTICLE{Rojas-NandayapaXie2017,
  AUTHOR    = {L. Rojas-Nandayapa and W. Xie},
  TITLE     = {Asympotoic tail behavior of phase-type scale mixture 
               distributions},
  YEAR      = {2017},
  PAGES     = {1--6},
  JOURNAL   = {Annals of Actuarial Science},
  PUBLISHER = {Cambridge University Press}}

@BOOK{BuchholzKriegeFelko2014,
  AUTHOR    = {P. Buchholz, J. Kriege, I. Felko},
  TITLE     = {Phase-Type Distributions},
  PUBLISHER = {Springer},
  YEAR      = {2014},
  PAGES     = {5--10, 125--128}}

@ARTICLE{BladtNandayapapa2017,
  AUTHOR    = {M. Bladt and L. Nandayapapa},
  TITLE     = {Fitting Phase-type Mixtures to Heavy-tailed Data and 
               Distriutions},
  YEAR      = {2017},
  JOURNAL   = {arXiv preprint arXiv:1705.04357},
  PAGES     = {1--11}}

@article{AhmSoohanKimJosephRamaswani2012,
  AUTHOR    = {Ahn, Soohan and H.T. Kim, Joseph and Ramaswami, V},
  TITLE     = {A New Class of Models for Heavy Tailed Distributions in 
               Finance and Insurance Risk},
  YEAR      = {2012},
  MONTH     = {07},
  VOLUME    = {51},
  BOOKTITLE = {Insurance: Mathematics and Economics},
  journal   = {MISSING},
}

@misc{wikipedia2017,
  AUTHOR       = {Wikipedia},
  TITLE        = {Heavy-tailed distribution},
  HOWPUBLISHED = {\url{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heavy-tailed_distribution}},
  LAST_EDITED  = {10 June 2017}, 
  NOTE         = {"[Online; accessed 10 June 2017]"}}

 @misc{Zheng,
  AURTHOR      = {S. Zheng},
  TITLE        = {Sufficient Statistics and Exponential Family Lecturer},
  YEAR         = {n.d},
  HOWPUBLISHED = {\url{http://people.missouristate.edu/songfengzheng/Teaching/MTH541/Lecture%20notes/Sufficient.pdf}},
  NOTE         = {"[Online; accessed 31 June 2017]"}}

@misc{Clapham2016,
  AURTHOR      = {M.E. Clapham},
  TITLE        = {Maximum likelihood estimation},
  YEAR         = {2016},
  HOWPUBLISHED = {\url{https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2vh98ful3_M}},
  LAST_EDITED  = {05 March 2016}, 
  NOTE         = {"[Online; accessed 01 August 2017]"}}

@misc{Andale2015,
  AURTHOR      = {Andale},
  TITLE        = {Pareto Distribution Definition},
  YEAR         = {2015},
  HOWPUBLISHED = {\url{http://www.statisticshowto.com/pareto-distribution}},
  LAST_EDITED  = {06 May 2015}, 
  NOTE         = {"[Online; accessed 22 July 2017]"}}

@phdthesis{Vatamidou2015,
  AUTHOR = {Vatamidou, Eleni},
  TITLE  = {Error analysis of structured Markov chains},
  YEAR   = {2015},
  SCHOOL = {Technische Universiteit Eindhoven}}  

@article{AsmussenNermanOlsson1996,
  AUTHOR    = {S. Asmussen and O. Nerman and M. Olsson}, 
  TITLE     = {Fitting Phase-Type Distributions via the EM Algorithm},
  YEAR      = {1996},
  ISSN      = {03036898, 14679469},
  URL       = {http://www.jstor.org/stable/4616418}, 
  JOURNAL   = {Scandinavian Journal of Statistics}, 
  NUMBER    = {4},
  PAGES     = {419--441},
  PUBLISHER = {Board of the Foundation of the Scandinavian Journal of 
               Statistics, Wiley},
  VOLUME    = {23}}

@article{Figueiredo2004,
  AUTHOR    = {Figueiredo, Mario AT}, 
  TITLE     = {Lecture Notes on the EM Algorithm},
  YEAR      = {2004},
  JOURNAL   = {\url{http://www.stat.duke.edu/courses/Spring06/sta376/Support/EM/EM.Mixtures.}},
  PUBLISHER = {Citeseer}}

@inproceedings{TaoRojasTaimre2016,
 AUTHOR       = {H. Yao and L. Rojas-Nandayapa and T. Taimre},
 TITLE        = {Estimating tail probabilities of random sums of infinite 
                 mixtures of phase-type distributions},
 YEAR         = {2016},
 BOOKTITLE    = {Proceedings of the 2016 Winter Simulation Conference},
 PAGES        = {347--358},
 ORGANISATION = {IEEE Press}}

@article{Breuer2014,
  AUTHOR   = {Breuer, Lothar},
  TITLE    = {Introduction to stochastic processes},
  YEAR     = {2014},
  JOURNAL  = {Lecture Notes, Univ. Kent}}

@phdthesis{Esparza2010,
  AUTHOR   = {Esparza, Luz Judith R and Nielsen, Bo Friis and 
              Bladt, Mogens},
  TITLE    = {Maximum likelihood estimation of phase-type distributions},
  YEAR     = {2010},
  SCHOOL   = {Technical University of DenmarkDanmarks Tekniske Universitet, 
              Department of Applied Mathematics and Computer 
              ScienceInstitut for Matematik og Computer Science},
}
@article{Brazauskas2016,
  AUTHOR    = {V. Brazauskas and A. Kleefeld},
  TITLE     = {Modeling severity and measuring tail risk of Norwegian fire 
               claims},
  YEAR      = {2016},
  JOURNAL   = {North American Actuarial Journal},
  VOLUME    = {20},
  NUMBER    = {1},
  PAGES     = {1--16},
  PUBLISHER = {Taylor \& Francis}}

@article{Dempster1977,
  AUTHOR    = {Dempster, Arthur P and Laird, Nan M and Rubin, Donald B},
  TITLE     = {Maximum likelihood from incomplete data via the EM 
               algorithm},
  YEAR      = {1977},
  JOURNAL   = {Journal of the royal statistical society. Series B 
               (methodological)},
  PAGES     = {1--38},
  PUBLISHER = {JSTOR}}

@article{Borman2004,
  AUTHOR    = {Borman, Sean},
  TITLE     = {The expectation maximization algorithm - a short tutorial},
  YEAR      = {2004},
  JOURNAL   = {Submitted for publication},
  PAGES     = {1--9}}

@misc{wikipediaPowerLaw2017,
  AUTHOR       = {Wikipedia},
  TITLE        = {Power Law},
  HOWPUBLISHED = {\url{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_law}},
  LAST_EDITED  = {12 July 2017}, 
  NOTE         = {"[Online; accessed 12 July 2017]"}}

@book{Embrechts2013,
  AUTHOR    = {Embrechts, Paul and Kluppelberg, Claudia and 
               Mikosch, Thomas},
  TITLE     = {Modelling extremal events: for insurance and finance},
  YEAR      = {2013},
  VOLUME    = {33},
  PUBLISHER = {Springer Science \& Business Media}}

@misc{Mean2011,
  TITLE        = {The mean excess loss function},
  YEAR         = {2011},
  HOWPUBLISHED = {\url{https://statisticalmodeling.wordpress.com/2011/06/25/the-mean-excess-loss-function/}},
  LAST_EDITED  = {25 June 2011}, 
  NOTE         = {"[Online; accessed 30 August 2017]"}}

@article{Genccay2001,
  TITLE        = {EVIM: A software package for extreme value analysis in 
                  MATLAB},
  AUTHOR       = {Genccay, Ramazan and Selccuk, Faruk and 
                  Ulugulyagci, Abdurrahman},
  JOURNAL      = {Studies in Nonlinear Dynamics \& Econometrics},
  VOLUMe       = {5},
  NUMBER       = {3},
  YEAR         = {2001},
}
@article{Mcneil1997,
  title={Estimating the tails of loss severity distributions using 
         extreme value theory},
  author={McNeil, Alexander J},
  journal={ASTIN Bulletin: The Journal of the IAA},
  volume={27},
  number={1},
  pages={117--137},
  year={1997},
  publisher={Cambridge University Press}}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{showframe}  % to visualise the typing area and margins
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

This is text with \cite{Goossens} and \cite{adams}.

\nocite{*} % to test all bib entrys
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

with the first pdf page:

[image: first pdf page]

Please change the used `\bibliographystyle` to that one you use. That could result in other errors ...

Answer (score 1):

In think, there are many problems/errors in the bibliography entries:

1. If you use URLs in the bibliography, you will have problems with the underscore character. I usually replace `_` with `\_` in the Bibtex entries. The result will show `_`. For instance,

   ```
   HOWPUBLISHED = {url{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_law}},
   ```

   may be changed to

   ```
   HOWPUBLISHED = {\url{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power\_law}},
   ```
2. There are some missing data

   - BibTeX to sort, need author or key in ParetoDist2011
   - BibTeX to sort, need author or key in Zheng
   - BibTeX to sort, need author or key in Clapham2016
   - BibTeX to sort, need author or key in Andale2015
   - BibTeX to sort, need author or key in Mean2011
   - BibTeX empty journal in AhmSoohanKimJosephRamaswani2012
   - BibTeX empty journal in FossKorshunovZachary2013
   - BibTeX there's a number but no volume in Genccay2001
3. And, some other problems

   - **line 13:** The `HOWPUBLISHED ={url{https://...}}`, use `url{` instead of `\url {... }`
   - **line 16:** You have `LAST EDITED` with an space in it. Even if this is not a valid field, it will not cause an error if the name does not have spaces.
   - **line 53:** The `{Wikipedia®}` has an special character
   - **line 55:** The same error with `HOWPUBLISHED`
   - **line 56:** The same error with `LAST EDITED`
   - **line 74:** The same error with `LAST EDITED`
   - **line 82:** The same error with `LAST EDITED`
   - **line 113:** The key `AsmussenNermanOlsson1996` is repeated
   - **line 168:** The same error with `LAST EDITED`
   - **line 185:** The same error with `LAST EDITED`